# How do I load a div element on click using only html?

Tags: html

So far I have the following;

```
<div onclick="this.nextElementSibling.style.display='block'; this.style.display='none'">
```

But instead of it just hiding the element using style I want the element to only load upon click. All the solutions I have found involve Javascript is there no way to modify the existing code I have?

Comment: Just to clarify: do you want to do this with pure HTML and CSS? No JS at all?

Comment: Well, considering you're *already* using inline JavaScript, I would imagine that yes, you need to expand on that :)

Comment: To clarify I am trying to get a video to appear after an image is clicked however it cannot simply be hidden using the code I have because it is set to autoplay and it will begin playing in the background when the page loads. I need it to only call the div element once the image is clicked.

Comment: @The Codesee I'm guessing that you hit a brick wall with this, I really appreciate you spending as much time as you have trying though, thanks.